# Inventory Architecture in Database

Tags: mysql, database-design, architecture, inventory

This is not a question related to a specific language, rather on the correct methodology of architectural of handling inventory.

Consider the following structure for storing software:

```
platforms (platformID*, platformName)
titles (titleID*, titleName)
```

And the following is a joiner table for unique products

```
products (platformID*, titleID*, releaseDate, notes)
```

And the following is a table I would like to keep track of my inventory

```
inventory (platformID*, titleID*, quantityAvailable)
```

In examples I have seen, others have created a table where each unique copy of a software is stored in a separate line as such:

```
software(softwareID*, softwareTitle)
inventory(inventoryID*, softwareID*)
```

I would like to know which approach is preferable? Should I create an inventoryID and thus a row for each unique software copy:

```
inventory(inventoryID*, platformID*(fk), titleID*(fk))
```

Or use a table that stores quantity instead, as such:

```
inventory(platformID*(fk), titleID*(fk), quantityAvailable)
```

Comment: I omitted an important detail from my question; that is, I plan to keep track of inventory that is out on loan. I'm unsure how that will impact my planning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also would start with quantityAvailable instead of lines for all the items. *But* I would still opt for an inventoryId, since cases could occur, where you have to dissect the entries with the same platform/title combination -- with an inventoryId you are more enhanceable in the future.

I would also recommend to add a further column: versionNo --- the version number of a software product. Sometimes you might have differing versions of the same product. When you have this, it is not a good idea to drop the information into the title (for example you want to search for all "Microsoft Office" products regardless of version ...).

Comment: Juergan, thank you for the response. I added a comment above that I omitted an important fact: I want to keep track of where an inventory item is (if it's a game, or a film, for example, I would like to track with which customer it presently is) and I am unsure of how that should impact my planning.

Comment: Hi Mel, I sounds to me that such information belongs to the inventory entity. Here is one of the reasons, an inventoryId would be helpful (as primary key of course) -- since you can get several inventory entries with differing properties. Of course you still can opt for one line per item -- since when your inventory oftentimes split-up, single entries are more easy to handle as summarized entries which you would have to split everytime one item is loaned to a customer ....

Comment: Another thought: You might want to have an own table for places (or customers) your inventory can go to (not only a text field).

Comment: Thanks Juergen. It's becoming so complicated that I will follow your suggestion and start with quantityAvailable. I will make additions as go forward and do some testing. I appreciate the advice.

Answer (score 2):

The advantage of having a unique row for each piece of inventory is that later if you want to keep track of things like inventory that's on layover, inventory that's on preorder, inventory that's been sold but could still be returned, etc.

I don't see any real disadvantage to this approach except that it's probably more work which might not pay off if these things aren't really needed.

Comment: Thanks, Pace. You may notice I unintentionally omitted an important detail when I asked my question: I plan to track inventory based on the customers who have it borrowed. For example, I would like to track where an inventory item is/with which customer.

Answer (score 1):

> Should I create an inventoryID and
>   thus a row for each unique software
>   copy?

There is no reason to do this, unless you want to store some information on each unique software copy, such as the date each copy was purchased. This is rarely pracitical in the inventory of software.

> Or use a table that stores quantity
>   instead?

You can also consider adding a `quantityAvailable` column in your products table, unless you think that eventually you'd want to have many inventories for each title, in order to be able to allocate a quantity of stock that is under special offer, that is soon going to expire, etc.

Comment: Thanks, Daniel, I added an additional comment to the bottom of the question that my change the complexion of the problem entirely: Tracking inventory based on a customer who has it out.